# How to include the blade file in to another blade file modal popup using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I developed the one product details blade file and I want to include another blade file inside the product details page modal popup and this blade file doesn't have a different layout. and I included the second blade file controllers in the product details page controller. Please help me with how to include this blade file.

I upload the file two files into GitHub

product detail page main blade
The calculator file is included blade file

https://github.com/Jerad30/new-project

Answer (score 3):

Let's imagine the blade file is located in `resources/views/view/another.blade.php`.
Then try it as following:

```
@include('view.another')
```

Comment: I include the file but first product details page css are not working?

Comment: If I include the blade file product detail page layout file in not loading.

Comment: What is your laravel version?

Comment: "laravel/framework": "7.24.*",

Comment: let me show your code.

Comment: I uploaded the files into github

Comment: The github link doesn't work. Please check